# Pyinstaller exe file is asking for admin password

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a script that moves a file from one location and places it on the users desktop, extracts the folders and creates a shortcut on the desktop to the exe file.  When I run the script from IDLE, it works fine.  Once I create an exe with pyinstaller, from the script below, it asks for admin password when you run the exe.  At my company we don't have admin privileges on our PCs.  Can anyone tell me what would cause the admin password request?

```
import zipfile
import os
import winshell
import ctypes
import shutil


filepath = os.path.expanduser("~\Desktop\\")
srcFile = 'I:\Decoder\Decoder.zip'
shutil.copyfile(srcFile, filepath +'Decoder.zip')
if os.path.isfile(filepath +'Decoder.zip'):

    with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath +'Decoder.zip','r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(filepath+'Decoder')


    link_filepath = os.path.join(winshell.desktop(), "Decoder-Shortcut.lnk")
    with winshell.shortcut(link_filepath) as link:
        link.path = filepath+'Decoder\dist\Decoder\Decoder.exe'
        link.description = "Shortcut to Decoder"

    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Decoder-shortcut has been added to your Desktop, Enjoy!", "Info", 1)

else:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Please Copy the Decoder.zip file to the desktop.!", "Info", 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PyInstaller makes the exe file it automatically makes it only openable with admin privileges. You would have to use something like py2exe or cx_Freeze so you do not have to do that!

Comment: But the exe file that I am making a shortcut to was made in the same way and it doesn't require admin privileges. That's why I thought it was something the program was doing.  I will try py2exe

Comment: If you use python three do cx_Freeze. With shortcuts depending on how you set them up they dont need admin privlages.

Comment: @PatrickONeill did you get it working? If so please mark my answer as correct so people in the future can fix this issue!